# How would I call an interface method in main?

Tags: java

I have an abstract method that is implemented on a class, but when I try to call this method from main, it doesn't show up on my methods list. All other methods show, except for the one coming from the interface. What did I do wrong?

```
public interface Printable {
    public void print();
}
```

Implements Printable.

```
@Override
    public void print() {
        for(int i = 0; i < getLength(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < getLength(); j++){
                System.out.println("o");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
```

Call in main, printable method not available.

```
if(shapes[i] instanceof Printable) {
    shapes[i]
}
```

Comment: try `Printable.class.cast(shapes[i]).print()`, your shapes[i] is probably of a type which is not Printable[] (otherwise your `instanceof` would make no sense and the method would auto-complete). Thus, cast the object to be of the "right" type (you can also do `((Printable) shapes[i]).print()`.

Comment: What is the declared type of `shapes[]`?

Comment: shapes array is of type Shape

Comment: not sure i follow , does the cast go inside of the if condition? or is the cast the condition? i've tried both ways and neither work

Comment: `if(shapes[i] instanceof Printable) {
    ((Printable) shapes[i]).print();
}`

Comment: Got it! Thanks Philipp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you checked whether the shape is printable here:

```
if(shapes[i] instanceof Printable){
```

the *compiler* does not know that you did. It still thinks that `shapes` is an array of `Shape`, which does not implement `Printable`. You have to tell the compiler "I have *indeed* checked that `shape[i]` *is* printable, so print it!"

How to tell it that then?

Cast!

```
if(shapes[i] instanceof Printable){
    ((Printable)shape[i]).print();
}
```

You might have used this `(type)value` syntax before. It forcefully converts the `value` into the `type`. You probably have used it to convert a `float` value to `int`. It's the same thing here!

Answer (score 0):

Your class, that implements printable, must declare "implements Printable", it's not enough just to have the right method

Also this:

```
if(shapes[i] instanceof Printable){
     shapes[i]
}
```

Does not call print

If your base array type is of a class that doesn't implement Printable, you can change it to use what Philipp wrote

```
class Base {}

class Shape extends Base implements Printable {
    void print()...
}

Base[] shapes = ....;

if(shapes[i] instanceof Printable) {
    Printable.class.cast(shapes[i]).print()   
}
```

Or

```
class Shape implements Printable {
    void print()...
}

Shape[] shapes = ....;

Shapes[i].print(); // no instanceof or cast necessary
```